# Multilingual Tabs - Different titles

Tags: facebook, tabs, multilingual

We have developed multilingual Facebook tabs/apps for our customer. So when somebody uses Facebook in english, the tab is shown in english. When someone uses Facebook in german, the same tab is shown in german. So far so good.

Our problem is, that we can only give one title. So the title of the tab isn't correct depending on language setting.
Is there any possibility, that we can create different tabs and only the correct tab (with the correct language) is shown on the facebook page?

How would you solve this problem?

Thanks & greets

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the images for the tabs. render and apply accordingly to the tabs.